# Unit of a purely infinite, simple C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose that we have a purely infinite, simple C*-algebra with unit $1$. Can we find two projections $p,q$ both equivalent to the identity such that $1=p+q$ and $pq=0$?

Well, there are two projections equivalent to $1$ such that $pq=0$ but what can we can we say about $p+q$?

Comment: This property holds for purely infinite von-Neumann-algebras, and a proof can be found in Kadison/Ringrose. Have you tried to modify the proof given there? (I don't have a copy at hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot always get p + q = 1. We can see this using K-theory.

Suppose p,q are orthogonal projections, both Murray von-Neumann equivalent to 1, such that p + q = 1. Let [-] denote the class of a projection in K_0. Then we have

[1] = [p+q] = [p] + [q] = [1] + [1]

Thus [1] = 0. But the class of the unit is not always zero in K_0 of a purely infinite C*-algebra. For instance it is not zero in the Cuntz algebra O_3.